# JDBC doesn't seem to want to call DELETE PreparedStatement when batched for MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

When I run the code in non-batch mode it works:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(
        "DELETE FROM myTable WHERE id=58");
preparedStatement.execute();
```

However as soon as I try to run it in batch mode:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(
       "DELETE FROM myTable WHERE id=58");
preparedStatement.executeBatch();
```

It will no longer delete the entry from the table. All my `INSERTS` work perfectly well with `executeBatch`, in fact everything so far except the `DELETE` command. It doesn't come back with any kind of error, it just seems to ignore the command and skip over it. And if I inspect the number of columns affected by looking at the int[] returned it's empty (int[].length = 0).

Update: I don't believe it's a permission issue because the user account has full root privileges and access to all commands. And if it was a permission issue then it shouldn't work in non-batch mode.

Comment: is `id` a primary key?

Comment: yes it's a primary key

Comment: That code will fail with SQL Syntax Error. Try spelling the keywords correctly, i.e. `WHERE`, not `WERE`.

Comment: That's actually just an error in my sample code and not the error in my real code. Good catch though!!

Comment: Your deleting this not directly from the command line so i guess that the mysql server will log everything did you check the log file for errors?

Comment: You need to call `addBatch()` first, and you'd want to call it multiple times (why else do batching), so you need the statement to be parameterized using `?` markers. In short, **learn how `PreparedStatement` works**. There are a gazillion examples on the web, all you have to do is search for them.

Comment: That was it, I forgot to call addBatch for the delete code. I can't believe I missed that. Everywhere else I've included it. That was brutal. There's no warnings or error messages, etc., it's just omitted (as expected). And of course it only happened for my two delete statements :( That being said if you want to write up that answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Without `addBatch()`, it just executed a batch of size 0. Not technically an error, though I believe some JDBC drivers will throw exception.

Comment: I agree. Unfortunately I lost way too much time because I missed that. I knew better but I was blinded due to looking at it too many times.

I did see others with this same issue, wondering why a command wasn't called. Hopefully this will help others find the same stupid error I encountered.

Comment: It makes no sense to use execute batch with the example shown. Why do it at all?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel This is a sample out of context. There are additional SQL statements but as stated in the question they all worked except for this one.

Comment: In other words I was trying to isolate the issue to a specific line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that for the delete SQL statement for whatever reason I forgot to add the following line:

```
preparedStatement.addBatch();
```

Omitting this line means the `PreparedStatement` was never added to the batch and hence never executed. There are of course no warnings or errors because the SQL statement is never executed, it's just omitted. As there were other SQL batch `PreparedStatement` in the batch there was no need for an empty batch exception to be thrown (some drivers will throw an exception but this is not guaranteed so don't rely on it).

Therefore the correct code would be:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(
       "DELETE FROM myTable WHERE id=58");
preparedStatement.addBatch();
preparedStatement.executeBatch();
```

Now as pointed in a comment you would normally not want to execute a single SQL command with batching, the reason this was done was to isolate the issue to the specific SQL command.